# How to use LWC Component in VF Page? I tried many tutorials but none of them works

Tags: visualforce, lightning-aura-components, lightning-web-components, visualforce-component

I tried many online tutorials how to use **LWC components** in **VF Page**, but I stuck at only one result - VF Page is loaded properly but not showing LWC component. Only the VF Page heading is showing and nothing else.
Here is my code snippet -

**1. lwc_comp.html**

```
<template>
    <div>
        <h1>LWC Page</h1>
        <lightning-button label="Hello" onclick={handleclick}></lightning-button>
    </div>
</template>
```

**2. lwc_comp.js**

```
import { LightningElement, track } from 'lwc';

export default class walkTestLWC extends LightningElement {
    handleclick(){
        alert("LWC Button Working");
    }
}
```

**3. lwc_comp.js-meta.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<LightningComponentBundle xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <apiVersion>54.0</apiVersion>
    <isExposed>true</isExposed>
        <targets>
            <target>lightning__AppPage</target>
            <target>lightning__RecordPage</target>
            <target>lightning__HomePage</target>
            <target>lightning__Tab</target>            
        </targets>
</LightningComponentBundle>
```

**4. vf_page.vfp**

```
<apex:page applyBodyTag="false" showHeader="false" sidebar="false">
    <h1>VF Page</h1>
    
    <apex:includeLightning />
    <div id="LWCid"></div>
    <script>
    $Lightning.use("c:vfapp", function() { 
        $Lightning.createComponent("lwc_comp", {}, "LWCid", 
        function(cmp) {
            console.log('LWC Salesforce driller added in VF page");
        });
    )};
    </script>
</apex:page>
```

**5. vfapp.app**

```
<aura:application extends="ltng:outApp" access="GLOBAL">
    <aura:dependency resource="c:lwc_comp"/>
</aura:application>
```

I tried so many ways to solve this but nothing works.
Can anyone tell me what's the problem or I am doing some mistake?

Comment: Did you check the browser's console to see if there are errors?

Comment: Yes, I checked but none of the error are relevant to this problem